# click() not working for ajax jquery appended TD

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hi i have a ajax functionality which gets data from server side and added append td to table rows

```
 var str =$(".note-list");
$.ajax({    
            type: "GET",
            url: "abc.htm",

            success: function(msg){    
                 var s="<tr class='fc-staff'>";             

alert("success"+str);

            $.each( msg, function(i,value ) {

                     s=s+"<td class='fc-widget-content fc-first'>"+value+"<i      
        class='icon-remove'></i></td> ";


                });
            s=s+"</tr>";
            str.html(s);
            $("#popup").show();
        },
 error : function(e) {
        alert('Error: ' + e);
    }
    });

 });
```

For this td which get appended from above jquery click function not working.
Note. Its working for other td in other table

My jquery function

```
$("td").click(function() {
        alert("tdclicked"); // Its not working
        alert($(this).text());
    });
```

FUI,

The appended  sources are not showing even in view page source also, But in UI its coming[image]

My page source is

```
<table class="fc-border-separate note-list" style="width: 100%"
                                    cellspacing="0">
                // Not showing appended td                  
</table>
```

Help me to get the jquery function to work for this appended td.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @run live() is removed actually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are appending the `td` elements after the DOM has been loaded, you need to use a delegated event handler. Try this:

```
$(".note-list").on('click', 'td', function() {
    alert("tdclicked"); // Its not working
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: Mr.Rory McCrossan, Thanks for your response but Still its not working

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$("table").on('click', 'td', function() {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

you are adding the elements after the page is loaded so you have to delegate the `click` event .

for more info look into the jquery on docs http://api.jquery.com/on/

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing `str = $('.notelist')` as if it were one only element. You need to loop on all the tables that have this class.

Comment: No only one element is there in that class

Comment: Then why don't you use an id ?

Comment: After reading all the answers, this may not be why your code is not working. But at the very least, it's good design to use an id instead of a class when there is only one element which is ever going to carry that name.

Answer (score 0):

@Rory McCrossan said is right :) you can also do like this :

```
$(document).on("click", "#yourTableID td" , function() {
     doStuff();
});
```